# Вопрос про исключения

Tags: java, android

Недавно начал изучать Java под Android. Как я понял, исключения нужно брать в блок `try and catch`. При этом блоков `catch` может быть столько, сколько может быть исключений, и каждый класс  `Exception` отвечает за свое исключения.

1. Первый вопрос, правильно ли я понял?
2. За что отвечает класс `IOExceptoin` и из-за чего он может сработать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку принятый ответ не отвечает на первую часть вопроса:

> При этом блоков catch может быть столько, сколько может быть исключений, и каждый класс  Exception отвечает за свое исключения.

Можно так и так.

Поясню на примере, допустим есть код который выкидывает 2 типа исключений `IOException` и `SQLException`, возможны, грубо говоря 2 стратегии перехвата исключений:

**Типизированный перехват**

```
try {
   //blah-blah
   //какой-то код
}
catch(IOException ioEx) {
   //что-то делаем
}
catch(SQLException sqlEx) {
   //что-то делаем
}
```

**Нетипизированный перехват**

В этом случае будут перехвачены все исключения, для которых `Exception` является родителем

```
try {
   //blah-blah
   //какой-то код
}
catch(Exception ex) {
   //что-то делаем
}
```

Есть еще некая смесь обоих этих подходов для Java >= 7, когда в одном блоке `catch` можно указать список перехватываемых `Exception`

```
try {
   //blah-blah
   //какой-то код
}
catch(IOException|SQLException ex) {
   //что-то делаем
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> public class IOException extends Exception
>
> Signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred. This class is the general class of exceptions produced by failed or interrupted I/O operations.

Сигнализирует об ошибке во время чтения\записи в потоки. Про конкретные ошибки не скажу - не знаю.

[IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html)